# Files in Android Studio don't match files in file explorer

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, android-studio-3.0

I have run into this in a few different projects in Android Studio recently. I will launch AS, open a project and some files and see that they are completely wrong. Viewing the same files in another text editor shows the correct text. As you can see in this image, the files as seen in Android Studio are usually made of text from the Android SDK or similar.

[image]

I have tried invalidating the cache and synchronizing the files individually and on the project level. The only thing that I have found works is copying the text from another editor into Android Studio.

I would think it may be a virus on windows, but so far, I have only ever seen this in Android Studio.

Any help would be nice thank you.